# Chown permission denied on samba share

Tags: permissions, samba, chown, shared-folders

I have a linux device with samba and it shares a drive inside the network and allow to everyone to write, read etc

I have another linux device which mount the samba shared drive and I would execute, from this second device, a chown on a folder but I don't have the permission.